# SQL Server Agent job fails - "A connection [to a SSAS instance] cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running

Tags: sql-server, ssas

When I am trying to execute the SQL Server Agent job (drop a database on SSAS Tabular), I get the following error:

```
[136] Job Test reported: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.ConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2383
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.Connect()
   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag)
```

**My question is:** 
Why the job doesn't work when it is executed using SQL
Agent job and works when I drop the same database manually? What
should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: When you do it manually how do you connect to SSAS inside SSMS? SERVERNAME? SERVERNAME\TABULAR? Do you use the same when you setup your SQL Agent step? If you RDP to the server and open SSMS can you connect?

Comment: @GregGalloway, thanks. Your gave me a clue!

Answer (score 0):

For the connection between SQL Server Agent and SSAS to work executed steps should refer to the server instance as \.